Numerous errors migrating SpataLite database with GeoDjango
On a Windows machine, I am trying to run GeoDjango's makemigrations, but receiving numerous errors from a models.py file created from GeoDjango's inspectdb. The error block looks like:
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
whale.GeometryColumnsAuth.f_geometry_column: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor 'GeometryColumns.geometrycolumnsauth' for 'whale.GeometryColumnsAuth.f_geometry_column' clashes with reverse accessor for 'whale.GeometryColumnsAuth.f_table_name'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'whale.GeometryColumnsAuth.f_geometry_column' or 'whale.GeometryColumnsAuth.f_table_name'.
whale.GeometryColumnsAuth.f_geometry_column: (fields.E305) Reverse query name for 'whale.GeometryColumnsAuth.f_geometry_column' clashes with reverse query name for 'whale.GeometryColumnsAuth.f_table_name'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'whale.GeometryColumnsAuth.f_geometry_column' or 'whale.GeometryColumnsAuth.f_table_name'.
whale.GeometryColumnsAuth.f_table_name: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor 'GeometryColumns.geometrycolumnsauth' for 'whale.GeometryColumnsAuth.f_table_name' clashes with reverse accessor for 'whale.GeometryColumnsAuth.f_geometry_column'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'whale.GeometryColumnsAuth.f_table_name' or 'whale.GeometryColumnsAuth.f_geometry_column'.
whale.GeometryColumnsAuth.f_table_name: (fields.E305) Reverse query name for 'whale.GeometryColumnsAuth.f_table_name' clashes with reverse query name for 'whale.GeometryColumnsAuth.f_geometry_column'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'whale.GeometryColumnsAuth.f_table_name' or 'whale.GeometryColumnsAuth.f_geometry_column'.
whale.GeometryColumnsFieldInfos.f_geometry_column: (fields.E311) 'GeometryColumns.f_geometry_column' must be unique because it is referenced by a foreign key.
        HINT: Add unique=True to this field or add a UniqueConstraint (without condition) in the model Meta.constraints.
whale.GeometryColumnsStatistics.f_geometry_column: (fields.E311) 'GeometryColumns.f_geometry_column' must be unique because it is referenced by a foreign key.
        HINT: Add unique=True to this field or add a UniqueConstraint (without condition) in the model Meta.constraints.
whale.GeometryColumnsTime.f_geometry_column: (fields.E311) 'GeometryColumns.f_geometry_column' must be unique because it is referenced by a foreign key.
        HINT: Add unique=True to this field or add a UniqueConstraint (without condition) in the model Meta.constraints.
whale.ViewsGeometryColumns.f_geometry_column: (fields.E311) 'GeometryColumns.f_geometry_column' must be unique because it is referenced by a foreign key.
        HINT: Add unique=True to this field or add a UniqueConstraint (without condition) in the model Meta.constraints.
whale.ViewsGeometryColumnsAuth.view_geometry: (fields.E311) 'ViewsGeometryColumns.view_geometry' must be unique because it is referenced by a foreign key.
        HINT: Add unique=True to this field or add a UniqueConstraint (without condition) in the model Meta.constraints.
whale.ViewsGeometryColumnsFieldInfos.view_geometry: (fields.E311) 'ViewsGeometryColumns.view_geometry' must be unique because it is referenced by a foreign key.
        HINT: Add unique=True to this field or add a UniqueConstraint (without condition) in the model Meta.constraints.
whale.ViewsGeometryColumnsStatistics.view_geometry: (fields.E311) 'ViewsGeometryColumns.view_geometry' must be unique because it is referenced by a foreign key.
        HINT: Add unique=True to this field or add a UniqueConstraint (without condition) in the model Meta.constraints.
whale.VirtsGeometryColumnsAuth.virt_geometry: (fields.E311) 'VirtsGeometryColumns.virt_geometry' must be unique because it is referenced by a foreign key.
        HINT: Add unique=True to this field or add a UniqueConstraint (without condition) in the model Meta.constraints.
whale.VirtsGeometryColumnsFieldInfos.virt_geometry: (fields.E311) 'VirtsGeometryColumns.virt_geometry' must be unique because it is referenced by a foreign key.
        HINT: Add unique=True to this field or add a UniqueConstraint (without condition) in the model Meta.constraints.
whale.VirtsGeometryColumnsStatistics.virt_geometry: (fields.E311) 'VirtsGeometryColumns.virt_geometry' must be unique because it is referenced by a foreign key.
        HINT: Add unique=True to this field or add a UniqueConstraint (without condition) in the model Meta.constraints.

I am using Django version 5.0.7. Is there any easy solution to solving all of these errors?
